# IIB application backup options via mqsi commands

Tags: server, websphere, integration, messagebroker

I work on IIB and we have many applications deployed on integration nodes and each application has its own integration servers/execution groups.
The requirement is to take backup of particular integration server having its application and later restoring the backup.
I have been using mqsibackupbroker command which created the backup of integration server but has created complete folder structure of integration node with policies, repositories etc.
Is there any mqsi command to take backup and restore of specific application in integration node without impacting other applications in particular integration server.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is a command for that.

But it’s not really necessary, because you can restore the application buy redeploying its BAR.
So for application level backup, you need to save the latest BAR file of each application.

This may not be sufficient, if your applications are not stateless. But, how you store the internal state of your application depends on the developers, so they need to implement custom methods to back up and restore the internal state of the apps. Not even mqsibackupbroker takes care of that.

Comment: Okay so you say that there is no mechanism to retrieve the current bar/application deployed on any integration server? Because before deploying the latest bar into the integration node, we need to check what is the current version deployed in the node,as many developers can work on single application. Is there any way to get that please..

Comment: No, you can’t retrieve the current BAR. You need to set up a controlled deployment process, and save the latest BAR file when deploying. And the developers need to add version labels to your apps, so you can see the deployed version.